# Anonymous temporaries and class template argument deduction - gcc vs clang

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, template-argument-deduction, ctad

Consider the following code snippet:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    foo(T) { }
};

int main()
{
    foo{0};
}
```

**g++ 7** happily creates a temporary object of type `foo`, deducing `T = int`.

**clang++ 5 and 6** refuse to compile the code:

> ```
> error: expected unqualified-id
>     foo{0};
>        ^
> ```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AZDF7bb4dbs7DT5e)

---

Is this a clang bug, or is there something in the Standard that prevents *class template argument deduction* from kicking in for unnamed temporaries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clang bug ([#34091](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34091))

From [[dcl.type.class.deduct]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.class.deduct#2):

> A placeholder for a deduced class type can also be used in [...] **or as the *simple-type-specifier* in an [explicit type conversion (functional notation)](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type.conv#1)**. A placeholder for a deduced class type shall not appear in any other context. 
>   *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class T> struct container {
>     container(T t) {}
>     template<class Iter> container(Iter beg, Iter end);
> };
>
> template<class Iter>
> container(Iter b, Iter e) -> container<typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type>;
> std::vector<double> v = { /* ... */ };
>
> container c(7);                         // OK, deduces int for T
> auto d = container(v.begin(), v.end()); // OK, deduces double for T
> container e{5, 6};                      // error, int is not an iterator
> ```
>
> *— end example ]*